# Mootools Formcheck: Custom Function for Selectbox

Tags: javascript, validation, mootools, mootools1.2

I have problem with `Mootools formcheck` js when applying `custom function` to `Selectbox field`. **Custom Function** will be work fine with **Text Field**, but **Selectbox** is NOT.

My dummy code of Custom Function:

```
var customFunc = function customFuncF(el) {
    el.errors.push('Custom function!!!');
    return false;
};
```

And There are a simple form that I apply to a text field:

[image]

and

```
<input type="text" class="validate['%customFunc']" id="User_lastName" name="User[lastName]" >
```

-> It works fine with text field.

But when I apply `custom function` to `Selectbox field`, example as `Office list` in my simple form, it's seems not work and always returns `true`. My example code for Selectbox

```
<select id="User_officeId" class="validate['%customFunc']" name="User[officeId]" >
    <option selected="selected" value="">-Select Office-</option>
    <option value="1">Office A</option>
    <option value="2">Office B</option>
</select>
```

How can I apply `custom function` to `Selectbox field`?

Thanks,

Comment: Could you be more specific on which version of formcheck you are using and make a jsFiddle with a example of your problem? And also, does it have to work on MooTools 1.2?

Comment: @Sergio Version of formcheck is 1.6 with mootools 1.2.1. I'll post it in jsFiddle soon

Comment: did you manage to get the fiddle together?

Answer (score 0):

It was caused by your validate which excludes the keyword 'required'. In fact, the custom function works.

But in function 'manageError':

```
manageError : function(el, method) {
    ...
    } else if ((isValid || (!el.validation.contains('required') && !el.value))) {
        this.removeError(el);
        return true;
    }
    return true;
},
```

As no 'required' and no value in here, the pushed error was be removed. :(

You can add the word 'required' into validate[] or setup the value of first option to 0 instead of blank.